# TableView Content not showing on scrolling in IOS6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

I am implementing pagination in My project for geting 10 item in every call.
But it work properly in IOS7 (3.5" and 4") but in iPhone iOS6(without retina) not showing second call data, data are coming but not showing on screen.

Comment: Show us the code, which you have tried ?

Comment: You've broken the table view's datasource.

Comment: post your screen shot and relevant code